# Getting build error while "generate serialization assembly" set to "on/auto" but not while "off" in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, windows-server-2012

I'm getting the following error: **Task could not find "sgen.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86"**
My running OS is Windows Server 2012 R2. TFS 2010 installed, Microsoft SDK v7.0 are installed on server. Unlike Windows 7 and Windows 8, in registry Microsoft SDK v7.0 invisible under registry **"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0"** Morover Microsoft SDK v8.0 is seen as installed but only "Bootstrapper" folder included. But in Windows 8 (which vs2013 installed) "bin" folder is also included.Microsoft SDK v8.0 path.

I've tried to install microsoft windows SDK and WSE2012SDKInstaller to my build agent server.
After some research, I see that at first looking for v7.0 if not installed looking for v8.0. v7.0 includes "sgen.exe".
Also, after stand alone installation of related SDK's, I think it is not seen under registry where MsBuild looking for.

Finally, the only solution I have is "generate serialization assembly" set to "off".
Is there any solution that "generate serialization assembly" set to "on/auto" to build successfully?